# How can I prevent a program from changing my mouse pointer?

Tags: windows-10, mouse-cursor

I use windows 10, and I've set up my mouse pointer, with the default microsoft HID-compliant mouse driver, to be the "extra large" scheme so that the pointer is very large.

However, inside a custom and little known CAD program, the main drawing area changes my flat large cursor to a tiny 3D mouse pointer. I've googled how to prevent this and come across changing several registry settings, and changing group policy settings, etc. but it still doesn't stop this program from changing my mouse cursor.

Is there a global setting somewhere to ensure it's IMPOSSIBLE to change the mouse cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the cursor only changes when the software has focus, it's unlikely you can prevent this. It's not actually "changing" your cursor, it's merely hiding your cursor and doing it's own drawing at the location the mouse would be.

If you want to put a lot of effort into it, it may be possible to change the graphic used by altering the software itself.

Comment: Your answer is brilliant and led to the answer I needed. Using your information I installed resource hacker, a program which can edit the cursor image in most dll or exe files, and replaced it with the system cursor I'm using. Works great. If you could, for future googlers, include this comment in your answer, I wanted to give you the credit.

By the way, the cursor changes even when the software doesn't have focus (even on hover while another app has focus). Just FYI, but it still fixed the problem by replacing the resource.